is it possible to render world space canvas over other objects in unity?
for some pickable object, I display a UI canvas. It's attached to a scene gameObject. Sometimes the Canvas UI overlaps with some other objects. I need to make sure the UI is always renderer on top of other objects. is it possible?


I would solve this by using a "camera stack". Two cameras in the same position and with the same settings, but their "culling masks" set to different Layers to control what objects they render, and with one camera rendering first and the second rendering on top of it.
First, make sure that the game-objects with the world-space canvases have the "UI" layer set in the upper-right corner of their inspectors, and that nothing that isn't UI uses that layer.
If you are using the Standard Render pipeline:
On the first camera (the "everything but UI" camera) set:

Clear Flags: "Skybox" or "Solid color" (whatever you want to be the
background of your game)
Culling mask: Everything except "UI"
Depth: -1

On the second camera (the "UI" camera) set:

Clear Flags: "Depth Only"
Culling mask: Only "UI"
Depth: 0

The result of this setup is that the first camera renders the whole scene without the UI canvases. Then the second camera renders the whole scene with only the UI canvases, and draws all that on top of the output of the previous camera.
If you are using the Universal Render Pipeline (URP)
Camera stacking works a bit differently here.
Which camera renders what is still controlled via the "Culling Mask" property. So you still have a camera with "everything but UI" culling mask and the other with a "only UI" culling mask.
You don't have a "Depth" field or clear flags. You instead you set RenderType = "Base" for the "Everything but UI" camera and RenderType = "Overlay" for the "UI" camera. Then you add the overlay camera to the "Stack" list on the Camera component of the base camera.
If you have more than one overlay camera, then render order is determined by the order in the stack list, with the base camera always being the first camera to render.
More information on camera stacking with URP in the documentation.
If you are using the High-Definition Render Pipeline (HDRP)
...then I unfortunately can not be of much help to you, because I never worked with it. But this article from the documentation mentions a "Graphic Compositor" that is supposedly the way to do camera stacking in HDRP.

that almost worked with some differences. in new cameras there is no depth. i had to user overlay camera.

@virtouso What render pipeline are you using? URP? In that case camera stacking works a bit differently.

thanks for the update
